About a sentence with "all else being equal"
I just read the following sentence. Regardless of the meaning it tries to convey, is it grammatically correct?

Soundness is preferred over unsoundness all else being equal, but developer productivity sometimes matters more.

The part that makes me confused is "all else being equal". Why it was appended to the main part "Soundness is preferred over unsoundness" without a "when" or maybe something else in the middle?

Personally, I would have added a comma after "unsoundness."


Soundness is preferred over unsoundness all else being equal, but developer productivity sometimes matters more.

all else being equal is adverbial, and hence the construction is fine.
all else being equal is similar to the idiom all things being equal.  A similar example is given:

All things being equal, a person with a PhD should be getting a higher salary than someone with only a master's degree.

when is used only if what follows is a finite clause:

Soundness is preferred over unsoundness [when] all else [is] equal, but developer productivity sometimes matters more.

